# removing punctuation from dataframe does not work Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark and text processing. Could someone give some suggestion on the following issue I have.
I want to remove all the punctuations in a column of a dataframe. I saw some posts online related to this topic, still cannot figure out why my code does not work.
If I remove a single punctuation, for example, period, that seems work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
commaRep = udf(lambda x: x.replace('.', ' '))
df=df.withColumn('RD',commaRep('DELAY_REASON'))
df.display()
```

Before:
Late inbound FA crew from F_29. DD
After:
Late inbound FA crew from F_29  DD

However, if I do a loop for all the punctuations that I want to remove:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
punc = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
for ch in punc:
  commaRep = udf(lambda x: x.replace(ch, ' '))
  
df=df.withColumn('RD',commaRep('DELAY_REASON'))
df.display()
```

Then none of the punctuations got removed. for example, string like:
Ramp headset not working. Had to get a new one. sh
remains the same, I wonder what was wrong with the loop.

thanks for any help!
Daisy

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need an UDF. You can use spark built-in `regexp_replace`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df = spark.createDataFrame(
  ["a:;,|/dlk\\", "jnh'.-lk", "ldkc!o?@"],
  StringType()
).toDF("text")
df.show()

df.withColumn("no_punctuation", regexp_replace(
  "text",
  r"""[!\"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]""",
  " "
)).show()
```

I had to escape a few characters so that they are correctly handled in the regex expression (like `-`, `/`, `[`, `]`).

Comment: thank you for the help! that worked well! Do you mind if I ask why put a r in front of the string """ """?  for escape the characters, do you mean put them in \ \?

Comment: The `r` denotes a python raw string. Using it prevent python to interpret `\ ` in the string (for example instead of interpreting `\n` as a new line, it would litteraly use `\n`). I did that because I want the backslashes to be interpreted by the regex engine, and not by python.
And about the triple quotes, I used them to make sure that the single quote inside the pattern was not causing any issue.
To escape special characters, I indeed just put a backslash in front of them.

Comment: By the way do not hesitate to mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you!